# Is the contract code part of the blockchain or just the hash of the code?

Tags: blockchain

Almost certainly noob questions - but here goes:

1. does the Ethereum blockchain contain the contract code or just the hash of the code?
2. Does the Ethereum `State' contain contract code or just its hash?

Hope you can help. Thanks in advance :)

John

Answer (score 2):

1. The blockchain contains the bytecode, including the constructor and its parameters. The node then unwraps it and stores the bytecode, minus the constructor, in its local store. Use `web3.eth.getCode(contractAddress)` to retrieve this unwrapped bytecode.
2. The blockchain does not contain the state. The state is deducted from the blockchain. However the blockchain keeps the hash (the Merkle root) of the state.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am clear on point 1. Regarding point 2: I read in the whitepaper that the state consists of a key-value mapping between account objects. As you say, account objects contain byte code, so does it follow that the state (as derived from the blockchain) contains contract bytecode? Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, for each address, the EVM state contains: balance, code and storage. And perhaps more that I am not aware of.